# In Doctrine 2 ORM How do I use an entity that is already in my repository without issuing a new query?

Tags: php, orm, symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Given that I Fetch all my entities up front

```
// Get All Users
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select("u")->from->("User u");
$q = $qb->getQuery();
// Doesn't this store any entities returned in the repository?
$r = $q->getResult();
```

If I then interrogate my repository, I would expect it not to have to go back to the database to resolve my query - but it does. Why is this?

```
// Get a particular user
$user = $em->getRepository('\User')->findByName('JoeBloggs');

// Is generating another query same as above but with 'where' clause...
```

Is there any way that I can use one DQL query to populate my repo and then continue to interrogate the repo for entities without having to hit the DB every time?

As an aside is there any way to initially populate the repo using more than one DQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repositories in Doctrine are a façade for object storage, when in reality it is just an abstraction layer for accessing the database. It does not "hold on to" any of the objects that are returned from queries.

Doctrine keeps track of objects that have been loaded in the UnitOfWork, but the only index it keeps is on the identifier. So if you are using the find() function for an object that is already loaded, it will not hit the database, but any other query will.

While there is no built-in way to do what you are asking, Doctrine does allow you to create custom repository classes in which you could implement this yourself. Be careful though, as you may find that some of these lookups in PHP will be slower than performing a SQL query.

Comment: Are you saying that I should be able to do a query that loads all users, and then if I use 'find' (or any findByX / findOneByX etc) on the repository (and the object I am looking for has already been loaded) there shouldn't be another query? Because that's not what I'm seeing. If I load all my users, then issue a 'find' it is executing another query (Contrary to .... 'So if you are using the find() function for an object that is already loaded, it will not hit the database, but any other query will.') - Thanks

Comment: Only find($id) which uses the identifier. findByX and findOneByX will still do another SQL query no matter what.